# android show only one div webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

package com.example.myapplication;
Hi guys can you help me with displaying only one div in webview? I need LogOnBoard div and the rest can be hiden or smth

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://cufs.vulcan.net.pl/lebork/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2Flebork%2FFS%2FLS%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fuonetplus.vulcan.net.pl%252flebork%252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%26wctx%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fuonetplus.vulcan.net.pl%252flebork%252fLoginEndpoint.aspx");

    }
}
```

Comment: you probably want the form right? and then hide the other sibling divs to LogOnBoard.

Comment: I just want to see only logonboard div on app layout

Answer (score 1):

You can run a small set of javascript to remove, the div elements that you don't want.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('globalfooter').style.display = 'none';
```

If you run these three lines, you will remove the header and footers of the page.

It can be added by setting the webView to evaluate some javascript just like this.
`webView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display = 'none';", null);`

Comment: Hi im new to programming and im not sure how to use those javascript lines in my android studio project. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You should be able to use `webView.evaluateJavascript(" **input javascript here** ", null);` to run the lines of javascript.

Comment: webView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display = 'none'");                                                                                                   So I added this line and sadly its not working                                                         error: method evaluateJavascript in class WebView cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,ValueCallback<String>
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: You have forgot to set the callback function witch would probably be null in your case. try `webView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display = 'none';", null);`

Comment: It's working but the header is still there ,nothing changed in webview

Comment: and you put it after you loaded the content?